# Change image when page reload in jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, image

I am working in php on when user click image when it will redirect to another link then i need change image here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#cards").click(function() {
            d = new Date();
            $("#cards").attr("src","http://ifliptips.com/admin/VueGuides/images/ifliptips_hover.jpg?timestamp=" + new Date().getTime());
            $("#tips").attr("src","http://ifliptips.com/admin/VueGuides/images/iflipcards.jpg");
            $("#registeruser").attr("src","http://ifliptips.com/admin/VueGuides/images/reg_users.jpg");


        });
    });
</script>


  <?php
   $redirect=REDIRECT;

   $path=$redirect."/images/iflipcards.jpg";
?>
<li  class="active">
    <a href="quizcatagory.php" id="quizcatagory">
        <img id="cards" style="padding-top:15px" width=70 height=18  src=<?php echo $path; ?> />
    </a>
</li>
```

How can I change image after page reload?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
    url = "cardcatagory.php";
    $(location).attr('href', url);
```

The code above redirect your page to another link. Try below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#quizcatagory").click(function () {
        d = new Date();
        $("#cards").attr("src", "http://ifliptips.com/admin/VueGuides/images/ifliptips_hover.jpg?timestamp=" + new Date().getTime());
        $("#tips").attr("src", "http://ifliptips.com/admin/VueGuides/images/iflipcards.jpg");
        $("#registeruser").attr("src", "http://ifliptips.com/admin/VueGuides/images/reg_users.jpg");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: That will just attach the event listener when the page is loaded, not change the image on page load.

Comment: yes i know that but when redirect to another link then only image change

Answer (score 0):

You are already setting the image with a PHP variable

```
 <img id="cards" style="padding-top:15px" width=70 height=18  src=<?php echo $path; ?> />
```

Just change the image on the server side.  Unless you are speaking of the image urls in the JavaScript, then you can either make their values PHP variables and set that from the server or you can create a PHP file that returns an image and put all the necessary logic to determine what image to display from there. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php)